# Copy all files of one type from directory into one folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, directory, robocopy

This is a new one for me so I'm pretty much flying blind.

I have a folder at `192.168.1.2\mainFolder` that contains `folder1`, `folder2`, and `folder3`. Inside each of those folders are a handful of different file extentions, and a couple of files of each type. I need to take all files that exist inside `mainFolder` of the `.dep` type, and copy them to `192.168.1.2\copyFolder`

`copyFolder` will not have any folders inside it, but just many many files.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I have been told by TPTB that robocopy would be helpful, however I have never used robocopy and thought you guys may know of something better

Comment: Do you want all files in from the mainFolder and all its subfolders, or just the specified three folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you don't want `.dep` files inside `folder1`, 2 etc.? `Robocopy` / `xcopy` is usually a good choice. Powershell is slow for such a simple operation. If you just want the `.dep` files in `mainfolder` but not those inside the subfolders, try:

```
robocopy \\192.168.1.2\mainFolder \\192.168.1.2\copyFolder *.dep
```